# Invalid backend response. Error occurred on the server side. HTTP error 500 due to 12 directories and 115888 files in /home/user

Tags: php, elfinder

Whenever I open /home/user using elfinder, it gives:
Invalid backend response.
Error occurred on the server side.
HTTP error 500

This is happening because /home/user has 12 directories and 115888 files. The /home/user has a size of 5.5gb.
What do I need to add in the elfinder.php configuration file or any other file to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can change in .htacess file php_value memory_limit , php_value max_execution_time and Timeout (apache timeout)